# What is the difference between AWS sdk and AWS toolkit

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, sdk

I am starting using AWS and I am trying to understand the difference between AWS SDK (https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/net/) and AWS Toolkit (https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/)

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your first [link](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/net/)  provides the everything in your second [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.AWSToolkitforVisualStudio2017) and a lot more. This includes the SDK, Visual Studio Tools, etc.

The second [link](https://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/) is just the tools that integrate with Visual Studio 2017 with additional links for Visual Studio 2013/2015.

My recommendation is to install everything from the first [link](https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/net/) so that you can develop with Visual Studio and also be able to use [.NET CORE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/) which is a very cool platform for developing software that runs on Windows and Linux. You can even download the free [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) edition (I have not tested the Community version with the AWS SDK and Toolkit as I use the Professional version).

Comment: I installed the first but the templates for the "AWS" projects only appeared in the visual studio after I installed the second one. Thanks